# Failing to follow kinect tutorial

Tags: ros, kinect, roslaunch, ubuntu, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS in general. I have a kinect and want to follow the tutorial from
http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch/Tutorials/QuickStart
to see what kind of data comes out of the device.

The error I get when trying to run

`roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch`

is

```
[openni.launch] is neither a launch file in package [openni_launch] nor is [openni_launch] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Which led me to http://answers.ros.org/question/65363/when-i-typed-roslaunch-openni_launch-opennilaunch-it-says-is-not-a-package-or-launch-file-nameim-using-ubuntu-1204-and-groovy-im-new-to-ros-and-kinect/ which however did not fix the problem. I have tried quite some different packages to (re)install, however the error is always the same.

I have read through the tutorials about ROS filesystem etc, out of which the most most relevant seems to be the one about roslaunch (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRqtconsoleRoslaunch). However, for my problem, the system does not even seem to find the .launch file.

Can anybody help me with this issue? Has something changed, or am I too dump to understand the manual?

Software versions used: Ubuntu 14.04, ROS jade (have also tried the indigo packages)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214074/failing-to-follow-kinect-tutorial/) by [blubbi321](https://answers.ros.org/users/23248/blubbi321/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2015-07-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2015-07-19**:
If you `locate openni.launch`, do you get anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to install  ros-jade-openni-launch, apt-get tells me that it is not there.
So due to the fact that ROS Jade is new, the package was not built for Jade by its maintainer yet.
Thats why it does not find the package. Either you build openni for jade yourself, or you use ROS indigo.
Or ask the maintainer if he would be so kind to release it for you for jade.

Regards,

Christian

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0